# Levels of abstraction on AngularJS Architecture

Tags: angularjs, architecture, frontend

1) What are your considerations when planning the architecture of an AngularJS application?

What is your mental process?

2) Which criteria do you take in consideration to decide if you will:

2.a) Make each part of your application it's own module and inject each module to the main module as a dependency?

```
angular.module('WebsitePart1', []);
angular.module('WebsitePart2', []);
angular.module('Main', ['WebsitePart1','WebsitePart2']);
```

2.b) Create only one module, and attach everything else (directives, controllers, services, etc) to the main module?

```
var mynamespace = angular.module('', ['ngRoute']);
```

And then attach a controller to each router setup, attach the directives to the mynamespace module, etc.

Thank you for sharing your take on it!

Comment: go through this videos:https://egghead.io/series/angularjs-application-architecture,https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub

Comment: Yup, actually I had already watched those and many other videos from Egghead. I was just wondering if other people would have more insights or different takes on that subject. Here is an article about it: http://henriquat.re/modularizing-angularjs/modularizing-angular-applications/modularizing-angular-applications.html

But I would like to go deeper into the discussion, considering Apps of different sizes, from small apps to enterprise applications and the implications in each approach. Pros and Cons. Etc.